# Custom Core Image Filter for curves

Tags: ios, glsl, core-image, ios8, cifilter

Now that iOS 8 allows writing custom kernels for CIFilters, I wanted to try and implement curves for the seperate channels of an image.

I've tried following the guide and examples in [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_custom_filters/ci_custom_filters.html)  but couldn't figure out how to access the separate RGB channels within the kernel at all.

I do know about GPUImage but it would be great to find a solution using the given APIs only.

Comment: You can write custom filter. I'm trying, but can't get pixel color from prepared a curve image. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33891583/tone-curve-with-coreimage-filter

Comment: In my question I've presented kernel with access to separate RGB channels.